# Refresh/Reload portion of Python script without reload the whole script

Tags: python, loops, bots, refresh, telegram-bot

I have a personal project to create a Telegram bot using python. What I want is to reply to any question with a dynamic answer generate from a database query. I don't want to create data query for every request from bot, so my idea is to generate a set of data (data frame) and then bot can take the answer from there. To generate the data frame, I want to schedule/reload the part of the querying script for every x minutes. My goal is to create Python script which can reload only on querying data without reloading the whole script. is there any ways to do this?
Sample code:

```
tt = datetime.now()

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(----)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=----, password=----, dsn=dsn_tns)

cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = ("""select *
from TABLE
WHERE REPORTDATE > to_date(:tt,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')""")
param = {"tt": tt}

data = psql.read_sql(sql,conn)#,params = param)
conn.close()

x = 2314 #value from question via bot

answer = data[(data['number'] == x))]
```

The part I want to reload regularly is from tt until conn.close().

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you don't want to rerun the query for each bot request, this would make more sense. It seems like you could also have missing data if you do not update your data for each bot request.

However, you can just wrap the code between tt and conn.close() in a function which you can set to run periodically.

```
def update_data()
    global data
    tt = datetime.now()

    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(----)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=----, password=----, dsn=dsn_tns)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = ("""select *
    from TABLE
    WHERE REPORTDATE > to_date(:tt,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')""")
    param = {"tt": tt}

    data = psql.read_sql(sql,conn)#,params = param)
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Ah I see. So every request it will run the query. Thanks!